# Adding labels to a formula

Tags: equations, labels

I have a diagram like this, explaining a formula:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\begin{document}
    $\stackrel[e+f+g+h^i]{a^b}{c d}$
\end{document}
```

For this example, I have removed the numbers.

- How can I scale this diagram up, so that each part appears exactly 300% larger?
- If I am using an OpenType font, will this scaling produce errors?
- How can I add labels to the formula describing what each part means?

Comment: Labelling each part could be done in a varied number of ways: footnotes, arrows pointing to elements or just a plain textual description. You need to be a little more specific about your needs.

Comment: I must label all parts separately ("a" gets a label, "b" gets a label). The labels contain short sentences as descriptions. I see that `underbrace`'s look very nice, but perhaps only can be used in cases where an item is very wide (which I might use in some places). Is there some other element that matches the style of `underbrace`, but can be used in situations where I must refer to a narrower item? Or place the label to the right or left?

Comment: Underbrackets are also an option, and the distance from the equation can be varied more directly. I think they look ugly though. Under braces can be used on quite short bits of maths too. The limitation is really just what the label is. I suggest labeling parts with letters and then referring to these letters in the text proper.

Comment: I added an alternative using align, which gives a bit more space.

Comment: Your last bullet point should have been asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`scalebox` should do the trick for you. You'll need the `graphicx` package. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\begin{document}

\scalebox{3}{
    $\stackrel[e+f+g+h^i]{a^b}{c d}$
}

\end{document}
```

For labels, you can use something like the following

```
\begin{equation}
H_{\mathrm{atom-light}}=
\underbrace{\frac{\hbar\omega_{\mathrm{a}}}{2}\sigma_3                      \rule[-12pt]{0pt}{5pt}}_{\mbox{atom}}
+\underbrace{\hbar\omega\left(a^\dagger a+\frac{1}{2}\right)                \rule[-12pt]{0pt}{5pt}}_{\mbox{field}}
-\underbrace{i\hbar g\left(a-a^\dagger\right)\left(\sigma^++\sigma^-\right) \rule[-12pt]{0pt}{5pt}}_{\mbox{interaction}}\,,
\end{equation}
```

The `underbraces` highlight a section, and those `rule` commands allow you to line them up by pushing the under braces down. Labels go in the `mbox`s,

The result is this

[image]

As noted by Werner, replacing `\mbox` with `\text` from the `amsmath` package is a little nicer because it sizes the text properly.

You may also want to consider breaking your equation over multiple lines with the `amsmath` package and `align`. This will give you more space.

```
\begin{align}
H_{\mathrm{atom-light}}=\ &\frac{\hbar\omega_{\mathrm{a}}}{2}\sigma_3  &&\mbox{atom}\\
&+\hbar\omega\left(a^\dagger a+\frac{1}{2}\right)                      &&\mbox{field}\\
&-i\hbar g\left(a-a^\dagger\right)\left(\sigma^++\sigma^-\right)\,.    &&\mbox{interaction}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Finally, inspired by Werner I've thrown this together with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
H_{\mathrm{atom-light}} = 
\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[draw=red,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m1)
    {$\displaystyle\frac{\hbar\omega_{\mathrm{a}}}{2}\sigma_3$};
    \node[above of=m1] (l1) {atom};
    \draw[-,red] (l1) -- (m1);
}
+
\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[draw=red,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m2)
    {$\displaystyle\hbar\omega\left(a^\dagger a+\frac{1}{2}\right)$};
    \node[above of=m2] (l2) {field};
    \draw[-,red] (l2) -- (m2);
}
-
\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[draw=red,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m3)
    {$\displaystyle i\hbar g\left(a-a^\dagger\right)\left(\sigma^++\sigma^-\right)$};
    \node[above of=m2] (l3) {interaction};
    \draw[-,red] (l3) -- (m3);
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

which is based on an equation based on an equation... which I first borrowed from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/). In your case however, perhaps it's best to build this from scratch in a TikZ picture. Remember, you can still put it into a `scalebox` after:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=20pt]
%
\tikzstyle{boxes}=[draw=red, rounded corners]
%
\node[boxes] (middle) {\Large$c d$};
\node[boxes,above of=middle] (top) {$\displaystyle a^b$};
\node[boxes,below of=middle] (bottom) {$\displaystyle e+f+g+h^i$};
%
\node[right of=top, node distance = 35pt] (toplabel) {the top};
\draw[red] (toplabel) -- (top);
\node[left of=middle, node distance = 45pt] (midlabel) {the middle};
\draw[red] (midlabel) -- (middle);
\node[below of=bottom, node distance = 25pt] (botlabel) {the bottom};
\draw[red] (botlabel) -- (bottom);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: The `underbrace`'s look very good. In rendering them, does TeX use the selected font or is this a custom drawing which will remain the same regardless of the font?

Comment: `mbox` will use the typeface from the text surrounding your equation.

Comment: Oh, do you mean the brace itself?

Comment: I think the brace is related to whichever typeface your math mode uses.

Comment: Yes, it's a rectangle with glyphs on either side.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Typesetting the labels in an `\mbox` necessarily reverts them to `\normalsize`. If you want to maintain the correct typesetting, see the difference using `\text` instead of `\mbox` and include [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Comment: @Werner: I know, however this project that Village is working on seems rather elaborate. I'd rather not drag additional packages in unless necessary. I'll put a note in though.

Answer (score 12):

Scaling in LaTeX is easily obtained by `\scalebox{<factor>}{<stuff>}` of the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). It works regardless of what `<stuff>` is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{stackrel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/stackrel
\begin{document}
$\stackrel[e+f+g+h^i]{a^b}{c d}$ \quad \scalebox{3}{$\stackrel[e+f+g+h^i]{a^b}{c d}$}
\end{document}
```

For adding labels to the components of your construction, you could use [`pst-node`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node) from the [`pstricks` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks). Here is a small mock-up, although I put the construction inside an `array`, for clearer presentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node
\newcommand{\node}[2]{\rnode{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\psset{nodesep=1pt}
\[
  \scalebox{3}{$\begin{array}{c}
    \node{a}{a}^{\node{b}{\mbox{\scriptsize$b$}}} \\
    \node{c}{c} \node{d}{d} \\
    \node{e}{e}+\node{f}{f}+\node{g}{g}+\node{h}{h}^{\node{i}{\mbox{\scriptsize$i$}}}
  \end{array}$}
  \uput{20pt}[135]{0}(a){\rnode{a-desc}{\text{This is $a$}}} \ncline{->}{a-desc}{a}
  \uput{3cm}[40]{0}(b){\rnode{b-desc}{\text{This is $b$}}} \ncline{->}{b-desc}{b}
  \uput{140pt}[l]{0}(c){\rnode{c-desc}{\text{This is $c$}}} \ncline{->}{c-desc}{c}
  \uput{5em}[r]{0}(d){\rnode{d-desc}{\text{This is $d$}}} \ncline{->}{d-desc}{d}
  \uput{20pt}[190]{0}(e){\rnode{e-desc}{\text{This is $e$}}} \ncline{->}{e-desc}{e}
  \uput{20pt}[235]{0}(f){\rnode{f-desc}{\text{This is $f$}}} \ncline{->}{f-desc}{f}
  \uput{20pt}[300]{0}(g){\rnode{g-desc}{\text{This is $g$}}} \ncline{->}{g-desc}{g}
  \uput{20pt}[320]{0}(h){\rnode{h-desc}{\text{This is $h$}}} \ncline{->}{h-desc}{h}
  \uput{20pt}[345]{0}(i){\rnode{i-desc}{\text{This is $i$}}} \ncline{->}{i-desc}{i}
\]
\end{document}
```

The macro `\node{<label>}{<stuff>}` was defined for ease-of-use. What is contained within the `\rnode`s used by `\node` can be anything, even a `\parbox` if you have long sentences/paragraphs. Also, since this approach uses the rich library of graphical components of `pstricks`, formatting of (say) `\ncline` is also possible.

Placement of the "element descriptors" (?-desc) is done using

```
\uput{<labelsep>}[<refangle>]{<rotation>}(x,y){<stuff>}
```

This places `<stuff>`, rotated by `<rotation>` degrees, at a distance `<labelsep>` and angle `<refangle>` from `x,y` (since we're using `pst-node`, `x,y` can be represented by a node). `<refangle>` can also be symbolic angle references, like `l`eft, `r`ight, `u`p, `d`own, or combinations of these (`ur`, `dl`, ...). My knowledge of [`tikz/pgf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) is limited, but this is also possible using that design medium; expect some answers using this tool.

Since this uses `pstricks`, you need to compile with either `xelatex` or a `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` sequence.