# What is the way to draw arrows to parts of text using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, labels

I have the following: I have a paragraph of code, and I would like to draw curved arrows pointing to specific parts of the program text, explaining it.

How can I do this in tikz other than experimenting with coordinates? Can I create location references while typesetting and then referring to these labels from tikz?

Comment: I guess you are looking for the `tikzmark` library. With no minimal working example that illustrates your issue in greater detail it's hard to tell though.

Comment: Thanks, I take a look at it

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86188/197451 -- are u looking for this

Comment: I don't need rounded boxes around formulae but yes