# latex loop back formula arrow

Tags: equations, chapters, arrows, loops, subequations

I would like to create an equation where 2nd equation is inupt to the first one. I want to write the equation in a figure.

[image]

I try using long arrow a

```
\begin{align}
%\begin{split}
         \rightarrow  \dotr{R}+O_2  &\longrightarrow \dotr{R00}
  %\end{split}
     \label{}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
%\begin{split}
         \dotr{R00} + RH &\longrightarrow ROOH + \dotr{R} \bigg\uparrow
  %\end{split}
     \label{}
\end{align}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134773/label-variables-of-equation-using-tikz-without-using-itemize for example. Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86188/labelling-with-arrows-in-an-automated-way.

Comment: please upload your code as a MWE

Comment: \begin{align}
%\begin{split}
         \rightarrow  \dotr{R}+O_2  &\longrightarrow \dotr{R00}
  %\end{split}
     \label{}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
%\begin{split}
         \dotr{R00} + RH &\longrightarrow ROOH + \dotr{R} \bigg\uparrow
  %\end{split}
     \label{}
\end{align}

Comment: your code does not compile

Comment: Where does the `\dotr` command come from?

Comment: @Bernard \dotr is used to put black dot on R. It was defined in the start of the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation in the figure is a chemical equation. Using Bernard's answer and the `mhchem` package (useful for writing chemical formulas, etc.), following is the code which you may use.  The [mhchem](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf) package takes care of the radical dots in the chemical equation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\usepackage[version=4, arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    &\rnode{R1}{\ce{R^{.}}} + \ce{O2 -> ROO^{.}} \\
    &\ce{ROO^{.} + RH ->}\rnode{R2}{\ce{R^{.}}}
    %
    \psset{linewidth=0.5pt, arrows=<-, arrowinset=0.5, nodesep=2pt}
    \ncloop[angleA=180, armA=1cm, angleB=-90, armB=0.20cm, linearc=0]{R1}{R2}%
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: chem quation with radical dots]

Comment: thank you for the reply. The bottom arrow is not appearing similarly to the previous answer.

Comment: I am using my university class file

Comment: How are you compiling the code? Compile the code using `XeLaTeX` or do this `LaTex (x2) -> DVItoPS  -> PStoPDF`.

Comment: I am using overleaf

Comment: In Overleaf, from setting menu, change the compiler from `pdfLaTex` to `XeLaTex`. You can get the settings by clicking the menu at the top left of Overleaf.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help. It works now. I highly appreciate your patience and help in this regard. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\ncloop` command from `pst-node`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\dotr}[1]{#1^{\bullet}}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \rnode{R1}{ \dotr{\mathrm{R}}}+\mathrm{O}_2 &\longrightarrow \dotr{\mathrm{ROO}}\\
     \dotr{\mathrm{ROO}} + \mathrm{RH} &\longrightarrow \mathrm{ROOH} +\dotr{ \rnode{R2}{\mathrm{R}}}
    %
    \psset{linewidth=0.5pt, arrows=<-, arrowinset=0.2, nodesep=2pt}
    \ncloop[angleA=180, armA=1cm, angleB=-90, armB=0.20cm, linearc=0.05]{R1}{R2}%
 \label{}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I don't know why the bottom arrow is not appearing in my document. Do I need to add any other package? thanks.

Comment: I am using my university article class