# Adding LONG labels to formula - not using "remember picture" option

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to add some labels to some text/formula. I have found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36863/adding-labels-to-a-formula) solution which is working fine in general. However, when I apply this to my test it looks like this:
[image: example formula]. 
I would however like for the text to stay (at least a little) closer together.

I would also prefer NOT to use a solution in which I need the option "remember picture" as I am afraid it could cause me problems elsewhere (got a bunch of `tikz` pictures throughout my document.

Below I have included my `tex` code.

Thanks!

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{tikz}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{equation}
        \nonumber
        1818AaCc-1day-14 => 
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[draw=blue,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m1)
            {$18$};
            \node[above of=m1] (l1) {$\theta_{B,CDD}$};
            \draw[<-,blue] (l1) -- (m1);
        }
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[draw=red,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m2)
            {$18$};
            \node[below of=m2] (l2) {$\theta_{B,HDD}$};
            \draw[<-,red] (l2) -- (m2);
        }
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[draw=blue,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m3)
            {$A$};
            \node[above of=m3] (l3) {$CDD_{L}$};
            \draw[<-,blue] (l3) -- (m3);
        }
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[draw=red,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m4)
            {$a$};
            \node[below of=m4] (l4) {$HDD_{L}$};
            \draw[<-,red] (l4) -- (m4);
        }
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[draw=green,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m5)
            {$A$};
            \node[above of=m5] (l5) {$DPH_{L,L}$};
            \draw[<-,green] (l5) -- (m5);
        }
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[draw=green,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m6)
            {$a$};
            \node[below of=m6] (l6) {$DPH_{L,U}$};
            \draw[<-,green] (l6) -- (m6);
        }
        -
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[draw=green,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m7)
            {$3$-day};
            \node[above of=m7] (l7) {$d_{inert}$};
            \draw[<-,green] (l7) -- (m7);
        }
        -
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[draw=green,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m8)
            {$14$};
            \node[below of=m8] (l8) {$\theta_{Dp,Crit}$};
            \draw[<-,green] (l8) -- (m8);
        }
        \end{equation}


        \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `overlay` option for the below and above nodes and use some `\hspace` and put the labels alternatively at different heights for clarity. I have also used `positioning` library for better results.

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \nonumber
    1818AaCc-1day-14 =>
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[draw=blue,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m1)
        {\strut$18$};
        \node[above = of m1,overlay] (l1) {$\theta_{B,CDD}$};
        \draw[<-,blue] (l1) -- (m1);
    }
    \hspace{1ex}\tikz[baseline]{
        \node[draw=red,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m2)
        {\strut$18$};
        \node[below = 3ex of m2,overlay] (l2) {$\theta_{B,HDD}$};
        \draw[<-,red] (l2) -- (m2);
    }
    \hspace{1ex}\tikz[baseline]{
        \node[draw=blue,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m3)
        {\strut$A$};
        \node[above = 3ex of m3,overlay] (l3) {$CDD_{L}$};
        \draw[<-,blue] (l3) -- (m3);
    }
    \hspace{1ex}\tikz[baseline]{
        \node[draw=red,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m4)
        {\strut$a$};
        \node[below = of m4,overlay] (l4) {$HDD_{L}$};
        \draw[<-,red] (l4) -- (m4);
    }
    \hspace{1ex}\tikz[baseline]{
        \node[draw=green,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m5)
        {\strut$A$};
        \node[above = of m5,overlay] (l5) {$DPH_{L,L}$};
        \draw[<-,green] (l5) -- (m5);
    }
    \hspace{1ex}\tikz[baseline]{
        \node[draw=green,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m6)
        {\strut$a$};
        \node[below = 3ex of m6,overlay] (l6) {$DPH_{L,U}$};
        \draw[<-,green] (l6) -- (m6);
    }
    -
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[draw=green,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m7)
        {\strut$3$-day};
        \node[above = of m7,overlay] (l7) {$d_{inert}$};
        \draw[<-,green] (l7) -- (m7);
    }
    -
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[draw=green,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m8)
        {\strut$14$};
        \node[below = of m8,overlay] (l8) {$\theta_{Dp,Crit}$};
        \draw[<-,green] (l8) -- (m8);
    }
    \end{equation}


    \end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust all the parameters I have introduced to suit your needs.

Comment: Thats a great solution. I have however one extra questions. Is there a way to get all the boxes to be the same height?

Comment: @MatoBehr Sure, add a `\strut` in all those nodes. Please see the update.